# PS3 doesn't boot with original hard drive after hard drive swap

Tags: technical-issues, ps3, hard-drive

I've messed up: I reformatted a new SSD for my PS3, but after that, when I try to swap to the original drive to get the backup data, it won't boot and asks me to reformat the whole drive. The older drive is in version 4.88 and the SSD in 4.90.

So I have two questions:

- How can I get the PS3 to read the older drive again?
- If I update the older drive via USB to 4.90, will it erase all my data?

Answer (score 24):

I've found a way to get it back up and running! In Safe Mode with the older hard drive, update it using USB:

1. Start the PS3 in Safe Mode
2. In Safe Mode select > System Update
3. Plug in the USB drive with the PS3 software update
4. Press START and SELECT at the same time, to search for the USB drive
5. It will start checking and start the software update
6. Then the system will restart and boot normally

*Reference*

- [How to get ps3 software update](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/hardware/ps3/system-software/)
- [How to enter save mode and start software update](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2tcTx2G2lM)